# Failed to find or create execution context for description IBScaleFactorDeviceTypeDescription: scaleFactor=2x

Tags: ios, xcode

My Xcode project suddenly fails to build. The complete error message (sans ids):

> Failed to find or create execution context for description 
>   IBCocoaTouchPlatformToolDescription: System content for
>   IBCocoaTouchFramework-NineOneAndLater
>   IBScaleFactorDeviceTypeDescription: scaleFactor=2x. 
>   These intermediate objects were non-nil

What I have done that may be related:

- update Xcode to Xcode Version 10.3 (10G8)
- open the project on a @1x MacBook Air after editing on a @2x MacBook (nothing apparent in git commits though)

What I have tried:

- clean build folder
- delete DerivedData
- restart Xcode

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try with:

```
sudo killall -9 com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService
```

Make sure Xcode is not running when run above command.

Restart your Mac will also help.

Comment: This worked even though I was not using the simulator at all.

Comment: Worked for me as well. That's a really weird bug.

Comment: I started getting this error as soon as I updated Xcode to 11.7. This solution fixed it for me.

Comment: Restart worked for me.